# Website block on a time schedule

Tags: websites, productivity

I would like to find a way to block the access to some websites from all the browsers of my Macbook, but not just as [Self-Control](http://selfcontrolapp.com/) does. I want to make kind of a time schedule, for example blocking Facebook between 8am and 8pm, and let it free outside this "window", and do the same with different "time-windows" for other websites... Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Self-Control to create a time-schedule. Check [here](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/wiki/Tweaking-Max-Block-Length-and-Block-Length-Interval) and [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100801214648362).

You could also use a browser extension, like [WasteNoTime](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wastenotime/enebomhlllfaccbelnjhfgblnalofhch). Goto Settings->Time Allowed->Edit Settings. Here you are able to create a time-schedule. It appears that you use several browsers. I know WasteNoTime is available for Chrome and Safari. Probably also for Firefox but I haven't checked.

I have not tried using different time-windows for different websites. Normally you want to block all disturbing websites at once. There are more browser extension which block websites, you would probably have to check them. Or you could install several such browser extensions and set them to different websites and time-frames.

Answer (score 3):

My preferred method of doing this is to use a DD-WRT router and block specific sites on a time basis. (See [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Access_Restrictions).)

Also, Netgear offers similar functionality in conjunction with OpenDNS. (See [here](http://www.netgear.com/lpc#one).)